# Using BoundaryNorm to set discrete colormap levels but also specify the centre of the colormap with DivergingNorm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to specify a colormap with discrete levels at specific values but also to specify where the centre of the cmap is aligned to.

```
frac_levels = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0]
frac_norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=frac_levels, ncolors=256)
```

This gives me a colormap with discrete boundaries at 0, 0.1, etc

If I use RedBu or any diverging colormap, 1.0 happens to be in the centre.

However, if my levels change to this:

```
frac_levels = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 15.0]
frac_norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=frac_levels, ncolors=256)
```

I'd still like 1.0 to be in the middle of the colormap but 2.0 is now in the centre. I can use `colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=0., vcenter=1.0., vmax=15)` or similar to define the midpoint but then it's a continuous colormap and no longer at the discrete bounds I want.

Is there a way to combine the two normalisation methods?

Edit: I could probably make a completely custom colormap only containing the colours I want but that doesn't seem a very good solution and would need to be customised each time my values change.

Comment: The tutorial on `TwoSlopeNorm` might be relevant: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#twoslopenorm-different-mapping-on-either-side-of-a-center

Comment: Thanks. I already looked through that but it doesn't seem to allow you to set discrete boundaries.